# alternate vertical timeline doesn't working

Tags: css, timeline

I created a vertical timeline and inserted this code to make the contents alternate left and right, but something is not working, because the contents are all positioned on the left. Can you tell me where I went wrong?

https://modern.wedding-site.it/

thank you so much

```
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block > .ct-div-block {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;}
.timeline_vertical:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    width: var(--line-width);
    height: 100%;
    background: var(--line-color);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateX(-50%);}  
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;}
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: var(--dot-size);
    height: var(--dot-size);
    border-radius: var(--dot-radius);
    border: var(--dot-border-width) solid var(--dot-border-color);
    background: var(--dot-background);
    z-index: 2;}   
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block:nth-child(2n-1)::before {
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
          transform: translateX(50%);}
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block:nth-child(2n)::before {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);} 
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block:nth-child(even) {
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
        align-self: flex-end; 
    -webkit-box-align: end; 
        -ms-flex-align: end; 
            align-items: flex-end;}
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block > .ct-text-block {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    right: -30px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);}
.timeline_vertical > .ct-div-block:nth-child(even) > .ct-text-block {
    left: -30px;
    top: -5px;
    right: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            transform: translateX(-100%);}
```

Comment: Note that no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in, perhaps, a decade.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the odd/even css rule got ignored because the parent is not the same (it has other parent between).

Change your code (or just add):

```
.oxy-dynamic-list .ct-div-block:nth-child(even) {
    -ms-flex-item-align: end;
    align-self: flex-end;
    -webkit-box-align: end;
    -ms-flex-align: end;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Note that no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in, perhaps, a decade.